# Word for neither taciturn nor garrulous

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means "saying the right amount; neither taciturn nor garrulous."

'Concise' is pretty close, but not quite the same, as speaking with concision seems to require a higher level of care than is necessary merely to avoid being either taciturn or garrulous.

Sample sentence: *Cyrus was* [insert word here], *as he was too casual for real concision, yet too tactful to be garrulous.*

I would prefer the solution to be a single word.

Comment: There are terms like well-spoken or articulate which indicate someone who is skilled at words, but they don't apply specifically to length. If you want a word that means using a midling number of words without passing any comment on their skill at speaking or the appositeness of their words, I suspect you're out of luck.

Comment: The concept of **balanced conversation** is very relevant here, and I'd probably used the term. But it's not single-word, and not an adjective applicable to a speaker.

Comment: The problem with this request is that what is special about Cyrus falls between the extremes of being brief and being verbose (garrulous).  There really is no single word for this ideal Aristotelian balance between the two extremes.  You could say that he was 'concise' (the nearest to the mean I can suggest.  Or you could just say that he was 'neither laconic not verbose'.

Comment: Your example sentence is itself an example of how Cyrus would say it. Concise would be: *Cyrus was too casual for concision, yet too tactful to be garrulous.*

Comment: I'd use *Goldilocks* as being just right: "Cyrus was *Goldilocks*, as..."

Answer (score 5):

Cyrus was **articulate**—too casual for real concision, yet too tactful to be garrulous.

**Articulate** (adj.)

> Able to express oneself clearly and well
>
> *The television crew covering the science fair were looking for
> photogenic and **articulate** students to explain their projects on
> the air.*
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/articulate)

> Able to express oneself fluently and coherently
>
> *An **articulate** lecturer*. Collins (print)

---

> A successful board of directors is likely to be much more than the
> aggregate of individual abilities—rather, it should function as a
> group with a clear purpose and be able to work together. This will be
> made easier if individual directors have good interpersonal skills,
> such as:
> ...
> • Communicating well. This is not merely a matter of being **articulate** and lucid, but also implies not being unnecessarily verbose or domineering, nor being silent when a view needs to be
> expressed.
> [Tom Wixley; *Corporate Governance, Fifth Ed.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=wheQDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA61&dq=articulate%20but%20not%20verbose&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsk9ftyYaEAxXovokEHQLGDfkQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=articulate%20but%20not%20verbose&f=false)  (2019)

> **Articulate**
> ...
> As an adjective, if you say that someone is ***articulate*** (pronounced *ar-TIK-u-lit*), you mean that he uses language (or puts his thoughts into wors) easily, fluently, and
> effectively. *An **articulate** speaker, conductor Leonard Bernstein
> (1918-1999) won fame for his ability to explain music clearly to
> people with little musical knowledge*.
> [Mark Phillips; *The Pinocchio
> Intermediate Vocabulary Builder*](https://books.google.com/books?id=jgxmDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA96&dq=%22articulate%20speaker%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7r57vmIeEAxWiMlkFHXb2ACMQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22articulate%20speaker%22&f=false) (2004)

> Being **articulate** means that a person expresses oneself readily,
> clearly and effectively.
> [Dawn Deeter-Schmelz et al; *Professional
> Selling*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rsq8EAAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&dq=articulate%20effective&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjShpikvoeEAxWyAHkGHXzEAMc4HhDoAXoECAwQAg#v=onepage&q=articulate%20effective&f=false) (2020)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can be both articulate and long-winded: certainly if you look at the synonyms of [articulate on Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/articulate). Maybe that's a slightly euphemistic use of "articulate" though.

Comment: @StuartF It's possible, but verbose may not fit the *well* in M-W's definition, "Able to express oneself clearly and well" Also,  two of the books  cited describe speaking articulately as also speaking **effectively**--a word not usually associated with someone who is long-winded.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "communicative"?  It can have the sense of "providing sufficient information" which is certainly not taciturn, but doesn't necessarily suggest the effusiveness of being garrulous.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more nuance...

- Cyrus would be 'succinct', if he was fastidious by nature.
- Cyrus would be 'terse' or 'brusque', he was a haughty person.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: *Terse* or *brusque* typically mean saying little and often too little (e.g. in an unmannerly way), so I don't think they apply here.